# Dual-axis Inclinometer

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, dual

Im working on a project where im designing a device that can be worn on the arm (using the elbow as the fixed angle). Once the device measures 45 degrees I want to program it to vibrate. My question is how can I integrate a dual-axis inclinometer to measure two axis instead of a tilt sensor that only measures one. What else do I use along with the inclinometer to make it operate? Also would i still need a comparator, voltage regulator, npn mosfet? Can I add a usb rechargeable battery?*disclaimer* I am not an electrical engineer. If there is any more information I can add let me know.

Comment: You are at the beginning of a steep learning curve. Fortunately, electronics is getting pretty big these days and there are a lot of resources available. Start with Arduino, make a prototype, then make a custom board. Be prepared to speed 100 hours or more learning.

Answer (score 1):

Much depends of the actual sensor you select.  Some sensors will output an analog voltage which may require additional circuitry, (or require an analog I/O port on a micro-controller).  Other sensor modules may have most of the circuitry included and may even have a simple digital output.

If you research available sensors the manufacturer may have data sheets or application sheets that gives a typical schematic, extra circuitry, interface components, or software that may be required to use the device.

Analog examples:
http://www.analog.com/media/en/reference-design-documentation/reference-designs/CN0189.pdf

http://www.meas-spec.com/downloads/E2-Series.pdf

USB example:
http://www.meas-spec.com/product/Position/DOG2-MEMS-Series-USB.aspx

RS232 example:
http://www.leveldevelopments.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/documents/LCH-45_Inclinometer_Sensor.pdf

Alternately have you considered just using two simple single axis tilt sensors?  Two simple digital inputs might be all that is required for a simple interface.

Lastly, be sure you want a inclinometer and not an accelerometer.  The first may only measure a changing angular position (eg.: a slowly moving arm), while the other can measure fast motion/acceleration and possibly multiple directions (eg.: a fast swinging arm).

Comment: A typical MEMS accelerometer works really well as an inclinometer too :)